# There was no Static Base method (Model Validation Extension code failed)

Tags: c#, inheritance, model, static, extension-methods

[Model Validation Extension code failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCVPn.png)

Hi everyone

I wanted to create a static base method instead of writing a Validate Method separately for each model, but it didn't happen.

Is there a way? or is it necessary to try another method?

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveMember(MemberPostModel postedMember)
    {
        if (postedMember.Validate()) return null;
        // other code ...
    }
```

Model

```
public class MemberPostModel : PostModelBase<MemberPostModel>, IDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties...
}
```

Base Model for Validation

```
public static class PostModelBase<TPostModel> where TPostModel : IDto
{
    public static bool Validate(this TPostModel postModel)
    {
        foreach (var prop in postModel.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var length = prop.GetValue(postModel)?.ToString().Length.ToInt32();
                var attr = prop.GetPropertyCustomAttribute<StringLengthAttribute>();
                if (attr == null) continue;
                if (attr.MaximumLength == length) continue;
                else return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I think firstly you should give up using static keywords
On other hand, you can use middleware or AOP instead of that
Also, you can create an abstract class and move save method here and when need to change, you can override your code.
Also, you can use some attributes or fluent API 
Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @malikmasis . I think I need to do research and have knowledge about Middleware and the AOP method. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be static at all? This looks like it should work if you simply remove the static keyword.
The static keyword on classes in C# doesn't do anything, except for preventing you from creating non-static methods.
In my opinion it makes sense to have separate validators for your models. What if you need to check some additional property in the future?

Comment: Then this is how it is used

[link](https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic619bf8836f3d8170715400)
[img](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/controller-action.png)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inherit a static class because they are sealed and abstract. If you need to inherit a class, you'll need to make it non static.